# Scrapy - TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Tags: python, scrapy, typeerror

I keep getting the following error when trying to run my scrapy program: TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments.  I have searched around but I cannot find anything to help solve my problem.  I do not know if I just have a typo that I am missing or something similar but any help would be greatly appreciated. The attached code is the portion of middlewares.py giving the error, its not the entire file.

```
# middlewares.py
import random
from copy import copy

class ProfileMiddleware:

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        mw = cls(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(mw.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        mw.settings = crawler.settings
        return mw

    def spider_opened(self, spider, **kwargs):
        proxies = self.settings.getlist('PROXIES')
        user_agents = self.settings.getlist('USER_AGENTS')
        self.profiles = list(zip(proxies, user_agents))
        self.queue = copy(self.profiles)
        random.shuffle(self.queue)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if not self.queue:
            self.queue = copy(self.profiles)
            random.shuffle(self.queue)

        profile = self.queue.pop()
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = profile[1]
        request.meta['proxy'] = profile[0]
```

Error code:

```
2019-05-23 10:10:51 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 172, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 176, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 98, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 140, in create_instance
    return objcls.from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trno224/scrapy_splash/scrapy_javascript/scrapy_javascript/middlewares.py", line 109, in from_crawler
    mw = cls(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
exceptions.TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

2019-05-23 10:10:51 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 98, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 140, in create_instance
    return objcls.from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trno224/scrapy_splash/scrapy_javascript/scrapy_javascript/middlewares.py", line 109, in from_crawler
    mw = cls(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```py
mw = cls(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
```

With:

```py
mw = cls(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or:

```py
mw = cls()
```

The `cls()` call is calling the constructor (`__init__()` method) of your class. Since your class has no constructor, the default constructor is used, which expects no parameters.